# Validate XML over XSD in C# with access to invalid element

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

I want to validate my XML file having XSD schemas. I use:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.AllowXmlAttributes
    | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints
    | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema        
    | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(settings_ValidationEventHandler);
settings.Schemas.Add(xsc);
var vreader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);
while (vreader.Read());
```

And if some error occured then I have beautiful human-readable information in my handler. But I want to know the node which caused the error. There is no access to object like XmlElement or something like this. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an easy way on how to do this... I would start by looking at the [SchemaInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.schemainfo.aspx) property associated with a node; intuitively, depending on the error, you might not get it at all...

The only other "key" between these might be the line/col number, which then can be cross indexed (you need to [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538465.aspx) then, is using Xml.Linq).